# how do i disable full disk encryption?

Tags: encryption, disk

As i'm a new user to linux while installing ubuntu i've choosed full disk encryption(it asks for the sda3_crypt password before login).
so how can i disable it without reinstall.,

Comment: You can't disable it.

Comment: If you just want to disable the prompt, see [this blogpost](http://atterer.org/linux-remove-disable-luks-encryption-password-on-disk-partition-crypttab-initrd)